"Operation not permitted" running dockerfile
The Dockerfile.native of quarkus looks as follows:
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-21:1.18
WORKDIR /work/
RUN chown 1001 /work \
    && chmod "g+rwX" /work \
    && chown 1001:root /work
COPY --chown=1001:root target/*-runner /work/application

EXPOSE 8080
USER 1001

ENTRYPOINT ["./application", "-Dquarkus.http.host=0.0.0.0"]

When running it I get the following output:
Step 1/7 : FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-21:1.18
 ---> 6cc5e74a214a
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /work/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5c8930078a21
Step 3/7 : RUN chown 1001 /work     && chmod "g+rwX" /work     && chown 1001:root /work
 ---> Running in b4310c07cfe5
chown: changing ownership of '/work': Operation not permitted
Error response from daemon: The command '/bin/sh -c chown 1001 /work     && chmod "g+rwX" /work     && chown 1001:root /work' returned a non-zero code: 1
Failed to deploy '<unknown> Dockerfile: my-first-quarkus-app/src/main/docker/Dockerfile.native': Can't retrieve image ID from build stream

I am running this on windows. Is there anything specific what I need to do to be able to execute chown on windows?

This has nothing to do with windows; this is a permission issue within the container. Try  adding a USER root before the WORKDIR /work/ in the dockerfile.
